# zfs on Linux: how to import an encrypted pool if you dont' know where key must be mounted?

Tags: zfs

I'm on a livecd with zfs.
I want to import an encrypted pool which has
a keyfile as "passphrase"

first I mount the usb dongle with keyfile

```
mkdir /tmpusb
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/uuidofdongle... /tmpusb
```

then I import the pool

```
zpool import -l -d /dev/disk/by-partlabel/ROOTPOOL1 -d /dev/disk/by-partlabel/ROOTPOOL2 -o altroot=/mnt rpool
1 / 1 keys successfully loaded
```

works all! What is the problem?

And If I forgot the correct dir where to mount the dongle?

zfs give me the correct answer but the pool must be open first!

```
zfs get all rpool|grep -i kyloc
rpool  keylocation           file:///tmpusb/cifry  local
```

The question is: there is a way to get this property with pool closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used ZFS over a decade now but have never used ZFS encryption, so while I know a lot about ZFS in general I'm certainly no expert on ZFS encryption.

AFAIK, you can't get the keylocation attribute of a dataset without the pool being imported (because it's an attribute of the dataset, not the pool - there may be a way to do it with the `zdb` ZFS debugging utility but if there is, I don't know it).

You can, however, override the attribute after the pool is imported but before you mount the dataset, and manually tell `zfs` where the key file is.

From reading the docs, I'm pretty sure that's what the `-L` option of `zfs load-key` is for.  From `man zfs-load-key`:

> `zfs load-key [-nr] [-L keylocation] -a|filesystem`
>
> Load the key for filesystem, allowing it and all children
> that inherit the keylocation property to be accessed.
>
> The key will be expected in the format specified by the
> keyformat and location specified by the keylocation
> property.  Note that if the keylocation is set to prompt
> the terminal will interactively wait for the key to be
> entered.
>
> Loading a key will not automatically mount the
> dataset.  If that functionality is desired, `zfs mount -l` will ask for the key and mount the dataset (see
> `zfs-mount`(8)).
>
> Once the key is loaded the keystatus
> property will become available.
>
> `-r` Recursively loads the keys for the specified
> filesystem and all descendent encryption roots.
>
> `-a` Loads the keys for all encryption roots in all
> imported pools.
>
> `-n` Do a dry-run ("No-op") load-key.  This will cause zfs
> to simply check that the provided key is correct.  This
> command may be run even if the key is already loaded.
>
> **`-L keylocation` - Use keylocation instead of the keylocation property.
> This will not change the value of the property on the
> dataset.  Note that if used with either `-r` or `-a`,
> keylocation may only be given as prompt.**

So, try something like:

1. mount the usb stick containing the key wherever you like
2. import the pool without loading the key because you want to override the `keylocation` attribute with `zfs load-key`.  Without the `-l` option, any encrypted datasets won't be mounted, which is what you want.
3. load the key(s) for the dataset(s)
4. mount the dataset(s).

```
zpool import rpool    # without the `-l` option!
zfs load-key -L /path/to/keyfile rpool
zfs mount rpool
```

BTW: keep in mind the distinction between the pool called `rpool` and the top-level dataset of that pool (also called `rpool`) - `zpool` sub-commands work with pools, `zfs` sub-commands work with datasets, zvols, snapshots, etc.